# capture JavaScript onClick JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a div that pops up when a user clicks on a link that will take them off of the english version of the site.  They are given a yes or no choice to proceed.  I have to capture the "URL" of where they will go to if they click yes.  This is easy on the links that are a hrefs, but some of the links are onClicks that execute JavaScript.  I have to capture the JavaScript, keep it from executing, and then execute it if they click yes.  This is the capture onClick code I've got, but how do I get it to work?

```
$_('a#foo').live('click', function(event) {
    var onclick = $(this).attr("onclick");
    $_('#yes a').attr('onclick', onclick);*/
    return false;
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

the yes button/div

```
$_('#yes').live('click', function() {
    if(href) {
        window.location=href;
    };
    if(onclick) {
        eval(onclick);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why `$_`? Normally it'd be `jQuery` or just `$`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HqW5R/1/)

Basically, if an onclick attribute is defined in the html, it'll be accessible as `somelink.onclick` which is just a function, so there's no need for `eval`

The trick is however, that code defined in an onclick-attribute will execute before the jQuery `live()` event handler, so you have to avoid that by removing the original onclick function but keeping a copy you can execute later.